# Wordpress - Only display first post title in list if multiple posts have the same title

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written a couple of shortcodes that display the titles of posts (events) per category, however I have some posts that have the same name, because they are the same event, but have a different date. These duplicate names in my list are sure to cause confusion to visitors and don't look good, so I want to only display the first post with the same name. I can't just change the names, because I have a different list that bundles posts with the same name together for a calendar. I'm using The Events Calendar btw.

So my question is: how do i apply a filter or an if statement to display only the first of a series of posts with the same title, while not impacting the display of posts without a duplicate name?

It looks a bit like this currently:

Category 
- crafting 
- drawing 
- origami <-- 
- origami <-- 
- origami <-- 
- woodworking

Origami appears thrice and I want it to only appear once.

My shortcode looks like this:

```
extract(
    shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        ),
        $atts
    )
);

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
);

ob_start();

$events = tribe_get_events( $args );

echo '<ul>';

foreach ($events as $event) {

    $parent = $event->post_parent;
    if(has_term(9,'tribe_events_cat', $event) && !$parent){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($event) . '">' . $event->post_title . '</a></li>';
    }
}

echo '</ul>';

wp_reset_query();
$retVal = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return $retVal;
```

I was thinking if it is possible to check if the previous item in the loop has the same title so I added the following to the if statement, but it didn't work sadly: 
    $prev = get_previous_post();

```
if($prev->post_title != $event->post_title){
```

Comment: could you store each event as a string in an array and check the array for the existence of the event name using strcmp through each iteration of the for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other way is to store all the posted title in an array and check the condition.

```
// create an array to store all the titles which are displyed        
$previous_posts = array();
foreach ($events as $event) {

    $parent = $event->post_parent;
    // add extra condition to check the title is not in previous posts array
    if(has_term(9,'tribe_events_cat', $event) && !$parent && !in_array($event->post_title,$previous_posts)){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($event) . '">' . $event->post_title . '</a></li>';

    }
    // store all the titles to array
    $previous_posts[] =  $event->post_title;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can push the results into a new array if they are not already there... something like:

```
$eventsArray = array();
foreach($events as $event){
  if ( in_array($event, $eventsArray) ) {
    continue;
  }
 $eventsArray[] = $event;
}
```

Comment: this answer better than checking previous event title because if there is a break between multiple titles OP code that checks previous post will fail